# How to zip a files but not include it's parent directories

Tags: zip

I am using the following code to zip a text file by using Cygwin.
master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'c:\apps\cygwin\bin\zip.exe -j "D:\ZipMe\TestZip\subdir1\random.zip" "D:\ZipMe\TestZip\subdir1\random.text"'

Now the problem is with the result that random.zip file also include the parent directories information. 
This code is working fine with old version but gave me odd result the verison ZIP 3.0.
Please help me out there.

Comment: the -j command is what strips the paths, if you are already using it and it is not working, i do not know

Answer (score 0):

In some version of Cygwin the Zip command has bug a which cause the -j option fail when Win32 paths are specified, So convert to POSIX paths and try this code...
c:\apps\cygwin\bin\zip.exe -j "/cygdrive/d/ZipMe/TestZip/subdir1/random.zip" "/cygdrive/d/ZipMe/TestZip/subdir1/random.text". Thanks.